# how to ckeck api response if include 404 error with javascript

Tags: javascript

i am fetching an api with this code and i knew how to check if the user input is null to dodge the error .. but i dont know how to do that again if the user input is invalid to the api ,

the code :

```
let dataToSend = {};
getweather = async () => {
  user_zip = document.querySelector("#zip").value;
  user_input = document.querySelector("#feelings").value;
  if (user_zip == "") {
    alert("Sorry My App Cant Send Empty Request to the API ");
  } else {
    let res = await fetch(baseurl + user_zip + apikey);
    try {
      var data = await res.json();
      var temp = Math.floor(data.main.temp - 273.15)
      var date = new Date()
      dataToSend.date = date;
      dataToSend.temp = temp;
      dataToSend.feels = user_input;
      postdata("/all", dataToSend);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
    }
  }
};
```

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not using try catch right , also maybe you need somthing like this `baseurl +"/"+ user_zip+"/" + apikey`:

```
 
    try {
      //this way you can catch error and dsplay them to really know why the api call failed 
      let res = await fetch(baseurl +"/"+ user_zip + "/" + apikey);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for helpeng , but i used another  if , else inside the try to check response.status.